# How to get the data of previous weeks in the same month knowing the day as a search point

Tags: sql, datetime, informix

How to get the previous week(s) in the month knowing the day .

for example if i have table like this :

```
emp_num   trans_date 
  22       1-10-2015
  22       5-10-2015
  22       7-10-2015
  22       11-10-2015
  22       14-10-2015
  22       19-10-2015
  22       27-10-2015
```

Now every month has 4 weeks .

So i  have a date like `11-10-2015` (in the second week)
i want to get the result of all previous weeks in the same month .
so in this example i want the result of the first week in Oct month like this :

```
emp_num   trans_date 
  22       1-10-2015
  22       5-10-2015
  22       7-10-2015
```

Note :

> ```
> The start day of the week is: sat
>
> The end day of the week is:Fri
> ```

Comment: "Now every month has 4 weeks " ???  I don't understand your question.  Can you elaborate on what *you*mean by month?

Comment: What if half of the week is in September and half in October? Do you want data from whole week, or just the part of the week that is in October?

Comment: i mean if i have a date like `11-10-2015` this date in the second week now i want all the data in the table in previous weeks in the same month .
i want to get the data of all previous weeks in the same month

Comment: @Aleksa: the part of the week in the same month or just `Oct`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, for October 2015, you anticipate the following results:

```
RunDate     Weekday  Result
01-10-2015  Thurs    [nothing]
02-10-2015  Fri      [nothing]
03-10-2015  Sat      01-10-2015, 02-10-2015
04-10-2015  Sun      01-10-2015, 02-10-2015 (same as above)
...
09-10-2015  Fri      01-10-2015, 02-10-2015 (same as above)
10-10-2015  Sat      01-10-2015, ... , 09-10-2015
...
16-10-2015  Fri      01-10-2015, ... , 09-10-2015 (same as above)
17-10-2015  Sat      01-10-2015, ... , 16-10-2015
20-10-2015  Tue      01-10-2015, ... , 16-10-2015 (same as above)
30-10-2015  Fri      01-10-2015, ... , 23-10-2015
31-10-2015  Sat      01-10-2015, ... , 30-10-2015
```

If that is the case, then the following query will do what you require:

```
SELECT trans_date, emp_num, COUNT(1)
  FROM transaction_table
  WHERE MONTH(trans_date) = MONTH(TODAY)
    AND YEAR(trans_date) = YEAR(TODAY)
    AND trans_date <= DECODE(WEEKDAY(TODAY),
                                6, TODAY -1,
                                TODAY - WEEKDAY(TODAY) -2)
GROUP BY 1, 2
ORDER BY 1, 2
```

The logic in the `DECODE()` is to manage the offset from the default behaviour of `WEEKDAY()`, where Sun => 0 and Sat => 6. The keyword `TODAY` in the query above can be replaced with a variable or any arbitrary single date.

Answer (score 0):

I havent worked in informix but here is how it looks like in SQL:

```
DECLARE @SomeDate DATE
SET @SomeDate = '2015-10-11'  

DECLARE @DayOfWeek INT
SELECT @DayOfWeek = ((DATEPART(dw, @SomeDate) ) % 7)

DECLARE @WeekStart DATE
SELECT @WeekStart = DATEADD(d, -@DayOfWeek, @SomeDate)

SELECT * FROM SomeTable 
WHERE MONTH(trans_date) = MONTH(@SomeDate) AND trans_date < @WeekStart
```

Comment: This looks a lot like SQL Server syntax.  Can you validate that this should work in Informix?